# Image as checkbox allowing only one selection

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I got two divs acting as a checkbox selection. I want to make only one div selected at a time so if I select option1, I see the red border on it, but if I select option 2, the red border should only be around option 2. Like a radio button behavior.

Also, is there a more efficient way to write the jquery? I feel like the two code chunks can be combined but not sure how exactly

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/fww2u1Lf/

```
$('#reg_option_1').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).is('.checked')) {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        $('#reg_option_1_check').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        $('#reg_option_1_check').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('#reg_option_2').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).is('.checked')) {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        $('#reg_option_2_check').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        $('#reg_option_2_check').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="registration_form_option" id="reg_option_1">Individual</div>
<div class="registration_form_option" id="reg_option_2">Business</div>


<input type="checkbox" id="reg_option_1_check" name="reg_option_1_check" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="reg_option_2_check" name="reg_option_2_check" value="2" />
```

Comment: they are acting as checkboxes, do you mean you want them to act like radio buttons?

Comment: Yes. So that only one can be selected at a time

Comment: Check my answer @user235196.. is that you wanted???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#reg_option_1,#reg_option_2').on('click', function () {
    $('.registration_form_option').not(this).removeClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        $('#'+this.id+'_check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/fww2u1Lf/5/)**

Comment: Short and simple! Thank you

Comment: @user235196 - In your original example clicking the already active box deactivates it. This answer doesn't do that.

Comment: i didn't want it to deactivate. @unknown did exactly how i wanted it

Answer (score 1):

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/occm1twj/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
    Group 1
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>

    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
 margin:5px;  
 display:relative;
}
.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;   
  margin:10px;
}
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
 margin:5px;  
 display:relative;
}
.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;   
  margin:10px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.childDiv').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
});
```

More simpler solution in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8rbncwj/)

Try it..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in pure css with radio buttons and pseudo selectors.

```
<input type="radio" id="reg_option_1" name="reg_option" value="1" />
<label class="registration_form_option" for="reg_option_1">Individual</label>
<input type="radio" id="reg_option_2" name="reg_option" value="2" />
<label class="registration_form_option" for="reg_option_2">Business</label>

[type=radio]{
    display:none;
}
[type=radio]:checked + label{
    border:solid 2px red
}
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fww2u1Lf/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten it to:

```
$('.registration_form_option').on('click', function () {
    $('.registration_form_option').not(this).removeClass('checked');
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',function(i){
        return  $('.registration_form_option').eq(i).hasClass('checked')
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fww2u1Lf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/fww2u1Lf/2/

I just reset everything before all action to get the desired result, it's not the most efficient. just a quick dirty fix.

```
$('#reg_option_1').on('click', function () {
        $('#reg_option_2_check').prop('checked', false);  // reset
        $('#reg_option_2').removeClass('checked');  // reset
        if (!$(this).is('.checked')) {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $('#reg_option_1_check').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $('#reg_option_1_check').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });

    $('#reg_option_2').on('click', function () {
        $('#reg_option_1_check').prop('checked', false);  // reset
        $('#reg_option_1').removeClass('checked');  // reset
        if (!$(this).is('.checked')) {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $('#reg_option_2_check').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $('#reg_option_2_check').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, plain and simple: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fww2u1Lf/3/)**

```
$('.registration_form_option').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).is('.checked')) {
        $('.registration_form_option').removeClass('checked');
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'_check').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        $('#reg_option_2_check').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```